# "Operation was slow and timed out" using Parse

Tags: parse-platform

we are working on an application using Parse as backend and we are experiencing some timeout problems since last week.

The issue we are facing is "operation was slow and timed out" with a 124 error code. We are getting this error some hundred times a day. The error is appearing both for simple requests with a limit of 1 result and for more complex requests.

Parse SDK version we are using is JavaScript.

Anyone experiencing this issue or any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked to see if you're exceeding your plan allocation for requests?

Comment: Hello Wain, request limit is ok, we are under 30 request per second while the error keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 1,000 objects per query.

- Keep in mind there's a **3 second timeout** in place for any query
- beforeSave/afterSave methods Cloud Functions should finish within **15
  seconds**
- Calling a Cloud Function counts as **1 API request**
- Using the Parse JavaScript SDK from within a Cloud Function will use API requests as always.

As suggested before, you should check :
https://www.parse.com/apps/NAMEOFYOURAPP#performance (replace NAMEOFYOURAPP by correct AppId)